# How to make a connection of IMAP in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow, hook, imap, imaplib

I'm Trying to make a connecting Imap in my Apache Airflow DAG, Can anybody show how to do a basic Imap connection in Apache Airflow.

Comment: I voted to close as needing debugging details. I think the key detail missing is why the many, many Python examples aren't suitable. Airflow uses Python, after all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow you can [create connections as environment variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#storing-a-connection-in-environment-variables) by using the convention of `AIRFLOW_CONN_{CONN_ID}` (all uppercase).
So for example you can have:

```
export AIRFLOW_CONN_IMAP_DEFAULT='imap://username:password@myimap.com:993?use_ssl=true'
```

or you can setup IMAP connection via the UI: [Admin -> Connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html).
You can follow IMAP provider [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-imap/stable/connections/imap.html) that explains how to setup the fields.